# WPF Popup disappear on Custom contextmenu opening

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup, wpf-controls

I have a TextBox in a PopUp. On clicking a ToggleButton, the PopUp Window opens.

**Toggle Button Code**

```
<ToggleButton Name="popupButton" Content="Click Me To Open Popup!" >
  <ToggleButton.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
      <Border Name="bg" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"  Background="Transparent" Width="17" Height="15">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="17" >
          <Path RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"  Data="M186,52 C208,52 230,52 252,52" Fill="Black" Margin="0,1.5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#457faa" StrokeThickness="2" />
          <Path RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"  Data="M186,52 C208,52 230,52 252,52" Fill="Black" Margin="0,1.5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#457faa" StrokeThickness="2" />
          <Path RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"  Data="M186,52 C208,52 230,52 252,52" Fill="Black" Margin="0,1.5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#457faa" StrokeThickness="2" />
        </StackPanel>
      </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </ToggleButton.Template>
</ToggleButton>
```

On clicking the ToggleButton it will open following the PopUp Window which contains the TextBox.

**Popup Window Code**

```
<Popup Name="testPopup" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=popupButton}" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=popupButton}" StaysOpen="False">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Content="Username: " Background="White"/>
    <TextBox Text="Please RightClick to copy the text." ContextMenuOpening="TextBox_ContextMenuOpening">
      <TextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
          <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"/>
        </ContextMenu>
      </TextBox.ContextMenu>
    </TextBox>    
  </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

When a user clicks on the TextBox in the PopUp I want to call the ContextMenu opening event which is as following:

**CodeBehind for ContextMenuOpening Event**

```
private void OpenContextMenu(FrameworkElement e)
{
    if (e.ContextMenu != null) 
    {
        e.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }
}

private void TextBox_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    this.OpenContextMenu(sender as FrameworkElement);
}
```

**Purpose to Call ContextMenuOpening**

I'm calling its opening event because I want to stop the parent contextmenu to open by `e.Handled = true`. Then I want to open the ContextMenu of the TextBox (source element). Here comes the issue.

**Issue**

As soon as I open the ContextMenu from code-behind, it opens the ContextMenu but the PopUp disappears as StayOpen property is set to False. I want to use StayOpen to False, as it should close as soon as the focus is lost.

Comment: So you want to stop textbox's contextmenu to open or Open it??! what do you want to do ultimately?

Comment: @AliJey I want to show contextmenu of textbox and handle that event so that it didn't bubbleup to it's parent and the parent contextmenu will not be shown.

Comment: And by parent you mean? You basically don't need any of the behind code... parents don't have any context menu!

Comment: Actully i'm using infragistics control [XamDockManager]. On clicking any popup that is contained in floating window shows context menu but i want to show contextmenu of textbox that is in popup.

Comment: Well I guess you should listen to XamDockManager's (or pane or ...) ContextMenuOpening Event and set e.Handled = true there!  TextBox it fine as it is. Have you tried that one?

Comment: Yeah i did. Buy the issue is, it will also block the textbox contextmenu too.